# Opencart display module only if user logged in

Tags: module, opencart

Is there any way in opencart to display sidebar modules only for logged in users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your quick reply. I found one simple solution.

Gone to my module controller

wrapped `$this->render();` with `if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) { $this->render(); }`

It's working great.

Comment: Yes, it is, but check my note at the end of my answer - in this case all the modules are populated, all the logic within the modules is done even the user is not logged in. This means that many DB queries that are not necessary for unlogged user are executed... My solution, when wrapping all the method's code, is better.

Answer (score 1):

Of course and there is also a simple collution!

Open up e.g. left column controller (`catalog/controller/common/column_left.php`) and after the line:

```
protected function index() {
```

add this condition (only with opening bracket):

```
    if($this->customer->isLogged()) {
```

now find the line

```
    $this->render();
```

and **before** it add this:

```
    } else {
        $this->data['modules'] = array();
    }
```

So the final code should look like this:

```
<?php  
class ControllerCommonColumnLeft extends Controller {
    protected function index() {
        if($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            // ... all the previous code up to the render() call
        } else {
            $this->data['modules'] = array();
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
```

Now do the same in `column_right.php`, `content_bottom.php` and `content_top.php` and You should be done ;-)

**EDIT**: One may also want to edit the concrete module controllers and add the condition there but this wouldn't be as simple and has other implications - there still would be a DB queries to gather all the available modules. Within my solution besides it's simplicity there is also a fact that for *unlogged* user no DB calls for modules will be done at all..